# Kentico CMS: Display the phrase that was searched for on a search results page

Tags: search, content-management-system, kentico

On my search results page I would like to display the phrase that the user searched for.

For example, instead of using the title **Search Results:** as you can see in the screenshot, I would instead like to use the title **Search Results for vitae:**

**Is it possible to pull in the searched word/s?**

At present the title is hard coded within the web part container that surrounds the search results web part.

**Screenshot of search results currently:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a response back from Kentico about how to do this. See solution below.

> Your **Search Results:** text is filled probably in the **Container title**
>   property of your smart search web part, so please just change it to
>   the following one:
>
> **Search Results for {?searchtext?}:**

This works perfectly! **{?searchtext?}** pulls in the searched word.